# Laravel force replace GET parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I want to force replace a get parameter.

```
$req->merge([
    'test' => '0'
]);

echo $req->get('test'); // Still shows old value ??
```

I want to force change the value in the `req` object. And I don't want to use `$req->all()` or anything like that.

**UPDATE**

Seems it works with `Illuminate\Http\Request` but not `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`, not sure it's a bug or a way to fix this?

Comment: try `$req['test']=0;`

Comment: nope, doesn't work @Karan

Comment: can you show your complete method code? @Rob

Comment: if $req is a instance of Illuminate\Http\Request try `$req->test = '0';`

Comment: ughhhh, it's indeed a `FormRequest` which seems to ignore `merge`, the regular `Request` class works.....  @porloscerrosΨ, but that's not really an option since it ignores auth, rules, etc.

Comment: `$temp = $req->merge([
    'test' => '0'
]); echo $temp->test;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

if u want to store using **object** then u **need to get by object**

```
$req->test = 0;
```

then u need to access by object only not key

```
$req->test  //output = 0;
```

**second** way if you merge by array then u need to access by **key** not **object**..

```
$req->merge([
    'test' => '0'
]);
```

then access by key only

```
$req['test'] //output '0'
```